# How do you safely remove TNT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Assuming GnomeSlice wasn't [referring to himself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20846/do-blasts-pass-through-obsidian) in the third person as the 'friend' who did all this:

[image]

A more direct (but boring) question would be, how do you safely remove TNT?

Comment: I'm flattered, but gnomeslice != Raven. You've got the wrong devilishly handsome Minecrafter.

Comment: I _guess_ you can remove it with Silk Touch, now?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[As of Beta 1.7](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history), TNT can only be detonated by fire or redstone, meaning it is now possible to remove placed TNT like any other block.

Comment: Aww, that's no fun.

Comment: We were real man back in the day, doing real engineering to remove TNT and we didn't have beds neither :P

Answer (score 24):

#### Note:

> *As of Beta 1.7, TNT can only be detonated by fire, redstone, and explosions, making this answer obsolete — recover your TNT as you would any other block.*

#### For Beta 1.6 and lower:

While you can't *recover* the TNT, you can *remove* it safely with water. TNT which is submerged in water when it detonates will not cause terrain damage or trigger nearby TNT. Be careful however, as it will still cause player damage.

With this much TNT, I'd personally play it safe and drop a source block on top of each block of TNT before setting any of them off.  Once placed, you should be able to remove all the TNT at once (albeit one at a time) without needing to introduce any more water.

I'll leave answering the follow-up question — how to remove all that water afterward — as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

Comment: Well it looks like it's on the coast near sea-level.  I'd be content with a new bay.

Comment: Absolutely!  Think positive.  ^.^

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?p=383544) over at the Minecraft forums seems to suggest that placing water next to a block of TNT will negate it, as apparently water will fill in the space occupied by the TNT once the TNT block is removed, thus 'absorbing' the explosion.

I haven't tried it myself, and I'm not sure how it'd work for the above image. :P