# What's the best way to remove mis-placed TNT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you safely remove TNT?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21293/how-do-you-safely-remove-tnt)

While loading up my TNT cannon, I accidentally placed a block of TNT where I shouldn't have. Firing up the machine will cause it to misfire and destroy itself and I'll have to build it all again. What should I do to remove the misplaced TNT?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*As of Beta 1.7, TNT can only be detonated by fire, redstone, and explosions, making this answer obsolete — recover your TNT as you would any other block.*

#### For Beta 1.6 and lower:

Put some water on top of your TNT block.
When TNT explodes under water, it doesn't deals damages to other blocs. Even better, it doesn't activate other TNT blocks.

Careful though, the explosion still hurts you. ;)