# What is the most efficient way to clear an area in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an underground village all planned out on graph paper, and am ready to start building it.  I have decided to have three block thick walls, with the middle being obsidian.  Overall, I need a space 53 blocks long, 53 blocks wide, and 31 blocks high.  What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you have mined obsidian on-hand or do you plan to do obsidian by cooling lava?

Comment: Alright, I know it is cheating, but I plan to use INVedit to build my village, but from then on I plan on playing legit.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral A quicker way to obtain materials inside the game is using [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-11-12w04a-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-jan-26/), which not only can give you items ingame but also allows you to set the time to sunrise again and to temporarily switch to creative mode so you can fly (quite helpful for building)

Comment: Alrighty, that sounds like a better idea.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[image: BOOOOOOOOOM!!!!!]

Comment: I know, I know.  But then I have a bunch of pits, and then the base that is below my bottom floor is not flat...  Funny though :)

Comment: Well you have a choice between mining every block, or blowing it to kingdom come and filling in the gaps. The latter is more efficient.

Comment: Awesome answer, and absolutely correct. Not to mention SOOO MUCH FUN *muahahah*...

Comment: @fredley one alternative is [WorldEdit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49103/88), but anyway +10 :-D

Answer (score 24):

A bit faster and more coordinated than [TNT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49095/88), but requiring a mod, is [WorldEdit](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit), which allows you to select regions and remove or replace blocks (all or only a certain kind, which is quite handy). I also recommend [WorldEditCUI](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/885099-11-worldeditcui-worldedit-client-user-interface-v11a/) then.

I'm not sure I understood your wall design, but to clear the area, let's say you stand on top of your future site and enter these [commands](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Reference) (omit the `#` comments!) into the console (<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
//pos1
//pos2                # select the block below you
//outset 26           # expand (53-1)/2 = 26 blocks in all directions
//contract 22 down    # that's 22 to much up because you wanted 31 only
//shift 4 down        # shift the selection 4 blocks down so you stay atop
//set 0               # make every selected block air
//outline stone       # make the outer wall stone
//inset 1             # make the selection 1 block smaller in each direction
//outline obsidian    # make the middle wall obsidian
//inset 1             # again 1 block smaller
//wall glowstone      # make the inner wall glowstone, leaving floor and ceiling air
```

Now the hole should be below the block you're standing on and be embedded in a stone-obsidian-glowstone stack. To quickly get through it, equip a pickaxe and enter `//` to toggle the [Super Pickaxe mode](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Super_pickaxe) which destroys any block with one click (`//` again to get the normal pickaxe properties back). Alternatively, equip a compass and right click below you, this will teleport you to the floor in your still isolated space.

Comment: Alright, I can try that.  +1

Comment: I'll race you, you download and install WorldEdit, I'll start placing TNT...

Comment: :)  I'm on my school computer, so I can't do that right now....

Comment: @fredley alright, the first time installation and familiarizing with WorldEdit may take some time, but in exchange you can then also easily add spheres or replace e.g. only dirt with snow...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I'm familiar with WorldEdit, it doesn't quite have the charm of blowing up a mountain of TNT though...

Comment: @fredley oh well, you win... Although a mod making the mountain literally explode might be even more fun :-7

Comment: @fredley: Ok done.  Did you get 9 gunpowder yet?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Touché

Comment: @CodeAdmiral I added one way (of probably many) how to clear the area

Comment: Best of both worlds? `/set 46` instead of `/set 0`. ;-)

Comment: @Ben [46](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/TNT)? Oh... [uhm](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20846/88)... Good idea :-)

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative to WorldEdit is [Zombe's modpack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-v110-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v510-upd-18jan/). The ['build' mod](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19090066/minecraft/readme.html#build) can be configured to work much like WorldEdit but without the console commands.

Once configured (your hotkeys will vary), you can select the corners of the box you wish to hollow out, then remove all the blocks first by changing them all to a single box then removing all of that one block.

**Step One:** Make selection by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, moving to the other corner, and pressing <kbd>X</kbd>again.

[image: Selected Cube]

**Step Two:** Fill the selection with your selected item (in this case dirt) by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: Fill With Dirt]

**Step Three:** Remove all of your selected item (again dirt) in the selection with <kbd>LSHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: Remove Dirt]

If you're looking to make outer walls, redefine your selection to be smaller after filling the area with stone or Obsidian.

Comment: hey thanks for pointing it out, I think I'll also have a look at it

Comment: yes, that's nice and quick. Can you directly select air blocks with zombe's modpack?

Comment: That looks sweet!  So does it just create a hollow cube, or is it solid?  +1 anyways

Comment: @TobiasKienzler—The block it uses is the block selected in your inventory, so you need some way of modding an air block in.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral—It creates a solid cube, but you can create a solid cube, hollow it out, and repeat. You would need to dig into the cube to find the corners, though, but the build mod also lets you destroy blocks in one click, and makes your inventory infinite, so it's not that hard.

Comment: @Dan I meant, how did your volume selection have air corners at the top, since with WorldEdit I think one can only select solid blocks which is why [I used commands](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49103/88)

Comment: @CodeAdmiral But since Zombe's modpack is based on WorldEdit, I guess you could still use `inset`

Comment: @TobiasKienzler—Zombe's build mod selects either the block containing your head or (by holding `CTRL`) the block containing your feet. So yes, you can (and must) select two air blocks to make the corners of your box. In my example I stood on the hill and placed the selection over my head, then went down in the valley and placed it at my feet.

Comment: @Dan ah, one more reason to have a look at it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a mod such as TooManyItems or InvEdit if you want a piece of land cleared very quickly, but that is no good if you're playing legit. If your playing properly I would suggest a diamond sword and a creeper rampage.

Comment: How exactly would going on a creeper rampage help?!

Comment: It's the first step in harvesting gunpowder.

Comment: BTW, I know this kid, he sits like right next to me at school.  What he is saying is that if you have a bunch of creepers, they can set of a chain explosion...

Comment: When you kill a creep, creepers drop gunpowder.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral that's actually a good point - why kill creepers when you can try to lead them to your construction site and _have_ them explode. [Mwahaha](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mwahaha)

Comment: Yeah that's what i was saying!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you could always find an underground cavern and build into the walls.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it legit sort of in creative the fastest way is to use potion of swiftness and just grind it out.. it takes longer to clean up after tnt than to just delete the blocks outright. I play on xbox so that is pretty much how I have to do it anyway

Comment: Yeah, it always bugs me how TNT tends to get launched into places you don't want it.  For instance, drill straight down to bedrock and place TNT all the way to sea level and you won't get a nice even hole, especially after the first time.